# Amazon web services - Connect Elastic Beanstalk with ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I have a node.js application running on an Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (EB) environment

in my app code I create an instance of memcached (my elastic cache) like this:

```
var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached('my-elastic-cache-configuration-endpoint:11211');
```

In creating my ElastiCache cluster I used the security group of the EC2 instance running my EB app.
And in that security group I have allowed inbound access on port 11211 as described here:
[Amazon ElastiCache Step 3: Authorize Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.AuthorizeAccess.html)

However my memcached ElastiCache is still not accessible from my app.

I have tested it locally to make sure the code is alright etc. and everything checks out.
Does anyone know what I may be missing?

Comment: EBS in AWS means Amazon Elastic Block Store. Normally we use EB for elastic-beanstalk.

Comment: you need share the error message, what error did you get? one test you can do is, you need make sure your application can connect to that port 11211, so you need test from the ec2 instance:

`telnet my-elastic-cache-configuration-endpoint 11211`

Comment: Thanks. After rebuilding app and reinstalling an Elastic cache than setting security groups again it now works.. I cannot really say what went wrong before because I am doing everything the same.. perhaps I was unaware of some EB setting in the first build